# Printer problems (system-config-printer broken) after update to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, python, printing

After I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 the dialog `system-config-printer` ran into problems when called from the command line (or via the GUI interface `unity-control-center`) :

```
$ system-config-printer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/system-config-printer/system-config-printer.py", line 62, in <module>
    import cups
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4: undefined symbol: __gmpn_cnd_sub_n
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

While doing a totally different task (`git clone` something) I ran into a similar error (this time it was `undefined symbol: __gmpn_cnd_add_n`).

And this post helped me out : https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/279649/228682.

You basically have to remove your custom installed version of `ligmp` by running

```
rm /usr/local/lib/libgmp.so*
```